# Should a completely flat tire be replaced?

Tags: tires, repair, replace

My tire has been completely flat for possibly 4 hours in my driveway before I took notice. I've removed it from the car and will be taking it in for repair in the morning.

Should I insist that a new tire gets installed? All 4 tires are about 6 months old and under full warranty I believe.

My fear is that the sidewall has been compromised.

[image]

I believe this is the source of the flat:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A tire is not necessarily damaged by sitting still for a short period of time like 4 hours.  Have the shop inspect it and see if they recommend it being repaired, since I assume there is a good reason why it's flat.

If it's a simple puncture and it can be patched and there is no evidence of sidewall damage, I'd keep it if it were mine.

UPDATED: Now that you've added the photo of the puncture, my recommendation is that you change the tire due to the location of the damage.  That close to the sidewall is problematic due to the amount of flex that happens in that part of the tire.  Chances are good that the tire shop will decline to repair in that area and you should heed their advice and NOT continue to use it.

Comment: I've added an image of what I believe is the source of the flat.

Comment: If that is the correct spot for the leak then the tire should be replaced.

Comment: In general it's dangerous and in many places illegal to patch a tyre if the patch would have to extend onto the sidewall (or if the sidewall is damaged). It's not dangerous to patch a tyre that's been flat for days, so long as it has not been driven on while flat.

Comment: The shop (GoodYear) immediately said that the tire needs replacement once they saw the source of the flat. Thank goodness for the road hazard warranty!